# Java design pattern to avoid duplication

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have the following classes

```
public class MyCustomFactory extends SomeOther3rdPartyFactory {

    // Return our custom behaviour for the 'string' type
    @Override
    public StringType stringType() {
        return new MyCustomStringType();
    }

    // Return our custom behaviour for the 'int' type
    @Override
    public IntType intType() {
        return new MyCustomIntType();
    }

    // same for boolean, array, object etc
}
```

Now, for example, the custom type classes:

```
public class MyCustomStringType extends StringType {
    @Override
    public void enrichWithProperty(final SomePropertyObject prop) {
        super.enrichWithProperty(prop);

        if (prop.getSomeAttribute("attribute01")) {
            this.doSomething();
            this.doSomethingElse();
        }

        if (prop.getSomeAttribute("attribute02")) {
            this.doSomethingYetAgain();
        }

        // other properties and actions
    }
}
```

But each custom type class like the string one above might have exactly the same `if (prop.getSomeAttribute("blah")) { // same thing; }`

Suppose I was to add another attribute, is there a nice way I can avoid having to duplicate `if` statements in each custom type class that needs it?  I can move each if statement to utility class but I still need to add the call to the method in the utility class.  I think we can do better.

Comment: So depending on whether `prop` has some attribute you want to do **different things**  or the **same things**?

Comment: They will all do the same thing if the prop has some attribute

Comment: I would iterate over all of the attributes of `prop`, and I would look each one up in a `Map<Attribute, ThingThatKnowsWhatToDoAboutIt>`.

Comment: Maybe update your question then to say `this.doSomething()` for all examples. It looks like you are calling different methods.

Comment: And if they all call the same method then anyhow why not just do `if(prop.getSomeAttribute("blah") || if(prop.getSomeAttribute("bleh"))`?

Comment: No I meant they will do different things, but the same `if` check and subsequent action can be in multiple type classes

Comment: But the doSomething() method in your example is defined in MyCustomStringType right? So no other class would know about it?

Comment: Actually no.  All the type classes can inherit from different classes.  So `MyCustomStringType extends (StringType extends (ValueType extends (SimpleType extends TheDaddy)))` but `MyCustomIntegerType extends (IntegerType extends (NumberType extends (ValueType extends (SimpleType extends TheDaddy))))`.  So ultimately they all have the same top level parent but `this.doSomething()` can be applicable to different custom type classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `Map<String, Consumer<MyCustomStringType>>`, where the key is your attribute name and value is the method call.

```
public class MyCustomStringType extends StringType {

    private final Map<String, Cosnumer<MyCustomStringType>> map = new HashMap<>();

    {
        map.put("attribute01", o -> {o.doSomething(); o.doSomethingElse();});
        map.put("attribute02", MyCustomStringType::doSomethingYetAgain);
        // other properties and actions
    }

    @Override
    public void enrichWithProperty(final SomePropertyObject prop) {
        super.enrichWithProperty(prop);

        map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> prop.getSomeAttribute(entry.getKey()))
            .forEach(entry -> entry.getValue().accept(MyCustomStringType.this));
    }
}
```

Depending on how you initialise this class (and whether this map is always the same), you might be able to turn in into static final immutable map.

I would also recommend naming it better, but a lot here depends on your domain and what this map and loop actually do.

Comment: Thanks.  This map needs to be global and shared between each custom type class.  We then need another map which maps the custom type to the attributes being used.  And then each `enrichWithProperty()` for each custom class should look the same - just iterating over these maps.  So the logic should be 'If this attribute is enabled for this custom type, then fetch the actions for this attribute from the other map and perform them'.  I realise I have shot myself in the foot with this example because in my real problem, the 'attribute' isn't a string but an annotation.

Comment: How does your if-statement look like if you have annotations? And for the global map, you can add another `.filter()` to filter by current class (you can make value to be a composite object - consumer plus something else that you can use in second `.filter()`)

Comment: It looks like `SomeAnnotation annotationInfo = prop.getAnnotationInfo(SomeAnnotation.class); if (annotationInfo != null) { this.setSomething(true); this.setSize(annotationInfo.sz()); }`

Comment: @artvandelay Then you can put `SomeAnnotation.class` as a key in your map and modify the `filter()` method accordingly.

Comment: Thanks.  So it would be `Map<Class<?>, Consumer<ParentType>>` but the lambda (Consumer function) needs the instance of annotation from the `prop.getAnnotationInfo(SomeAnnotation.class)` in most cases.

Comment: `.filter(entry -> prop.getAnnotationInfo(entry.getKey()) != null)` should do the job ;)